# FileNotFoundError. try using the full path with constructor syntax

Tags: python, file

Input :

```
from typing import Optional, List, Union
from torch_geometric.typing import OptPairTensor, Adj, Size, OptTensor

import torch
from torch import Tensor
from torch.nn import Parameter
import torch.nn.functional as F
from torch.nn import Sequential, Linear, ReLU, Dropout
from torch.nn import BatchNorm1d, LayerNorm, InstanceNorm1d


from torch_sparse import SparseTensor
from torch_scatter import scatter, scatter_softmax
from torch_geometric.nn.conv import MessagePassing
from torch_geometric.nn.norm import MessageNorm
```

Output :

```
FileNotFoundError: Could not find module 'C:\Users\won\anaconda3\envs\cpu_env\Lib\site-packages\torch_sparse\_convert.pyd' (or one of its dependencies). Try using the full path with constructor syntax.
```

Sorry, I'm very beginer.

I checked the file doesn't exist in the path, but it's in.
And actually I didn't understand what's "Try using the full path with constructor syntax". where should I put it in ? what's the problem with my file ? How can I run the code ?